# FMDB + SQLCipher Performance issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb, sqlcipher

We are making use of FMDB SQLCipher wrapper for handling the encryption of sqlite DB. We are having a single `FMDataBaseQueue` to handle read and write from multiple threads. Since the time we introduced SQLCipher , the application performance has taken a hit. On every transaction, we are setting the key.

```sql
self.dbQueue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback){
  [db setKey:"dummykey"];
  //Do Some DataBase Updates or Queries

}
```

So, we had to abstract out all the methods since it has been used by multiple controllers. How can we address this issue? And Sometimes we have to perform this main queue(Most of the time we do it in Global queue) since we wait for some processing to complete.
How can I improve the performance of the execution of sqlite statements since I feel that encrypting DB is a costly operation. 
The DBConnection is opened throughout the lifecycle of app. Should I use `[db setKey:"dummykey"];`every time I want to interact with the DB ?

Answer (score 0):

Please review the SQLCipher [performance guidance](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-performance/14) in comparison to your application usage.

Comment: The Document say "Do not repeatedly open and close connections, as key derivation is very expensive, by design. Frequent opening / closing of the database connection (e.g. for every query) is a very common cause of performance issues". We are having a singleton class having a single instance of FMDBDataBaseQueue and connection is opened during its initilisation. Does that mean that I should set the key only once  and not repeat in every DB Interaction ?

Comment: You only need to provide the key once when opening the database connection.